# SHA256 encryption in JAVA and PYTHON produce different results

Tags: java, python, sha256

I would appreciate your help to understand why my SHA256 encryption function in JAVA and in PYTHON does not produce the result (difference in 1 digit, one more in python):

hash to encrypt is: "thisisatest"
Java results is: `a7c96262c21db9a06fd49e307d694fd95f624569f9b35bb3ffacd88044f9787`
Python result is: 
`a7c96262c21db9a06fd49e307d694fd95f624569f9b35bb3ffacd880440f9787`

Python code:

```
import hashlib

def encrypt_string(hash_string):
    sha_signature = \
        hashlib.sha256(hash_string.encode()).hexdigest()
    return sha_signature


hash_string = "thisisatest"
print(encrypt_string(hash_string), end="")
```

Java code:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class OpenAPIPasswordEncryptor1 {


    private static MessageDigest sha256;

    // generated password is stored encrypted (using also user name for hashing)
    public synchronized static String encrypt(String hash) {
        try {

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.append(hash);

            // first time , encrypt user name , password and static key
            String encryptedCredentials = encryptionIterator(builder.toString());
           return encryptedCredentials;
        } 

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "";
    }

    private static String encryptionIterator(String content) {
        try {
            sha256 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            // append the static key to each iteration
            byte[] passBytes = (content).getBytes();
            sha256.reset();
            byte[] digested = sha256.digest(passBytes);
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < digested.length; i++) {
                sb.append(Integer.toHexString(0xff & digested[i]));
            }

            return sb.toString();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "";
    }

    // generate password for developers
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hash = "thisisatest";
        String encrypt = encrypt(hash);
        System.out.println("Your Password Is '" + encrypt + "'");
    }
}
```

Comment: Not necessary relevant, but you should always specify the encoding when using `String::getBytes`.

Comment: Your question is hard to read. Why did you mess with my beautifying edit?

Comment: @intentionallyleftblank - from some reason having trouble to mark my code properly here... not sure why

Comment: SHA is **not** encryption, use the Internet to learn the difference between encryption and cryptographic hashing.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that [`Integer.toHexString(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString-int-) drops the leading zero if the (unsigned) byte value is 15 or less.  As a quick workaround, you could use this:

```
sb.append(String.format("%02x", 0xff & digested[i]));
```

Although more efficient implementations are certainly possible.

To produce the same bug in Python, use this:

```
def encrypt_string(hash_string):
    sha_signature = hashlib.sha256(hash_string.encode()).digest()
    return "".join(["{:x}".format(b) for b in sha_signature])
```

Comment: Unfortunately at the moment the answer is yes, legacy systems :(

Comment: Okay, I added a Python implementation of the bug.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Great catch! Tripped me up as well.